# Rake db:create Error Terminal Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rake

I am getting this error when trying to run `rake db:create` I tried to uninstall and reinstall mysql too.. but it persists. Any direction on something like that?

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/brandon/Documents/GitHub/projectParent/project/.bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.4.10/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/brandon/Documents/GitHub/projectParent/project/.bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.4.10/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/brandon/Documents/GitHub/projectParent/project/.bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.4.10/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Comment: Try doing the following : `gem uninstall mysql2`

Then try `bundle install`

Comment: Did you install MySQL dev tools in your system? And also can you open MySQL client in your terminal?

Comment: @AkashAgarwal I did install it to my system and can start mysql in another terminal. I tried to uninstall via brew and via gem and reinstall but still no success.

Comment: @Brandon Try using the gem without rails, and also make sure the the dev tools for mysql are installed. Maybe your paths aren't set correctly. if you read the `Reason:`, its pointing to a path, see if the gem is available there. Also verify if the the required files are available at other paths mentioned in the error.